# How to modify cookies in Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I couldn't find any documentations regarding cookies modification in the official website, i.e. no api doc for `requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar`.

For example,

```
session = requests.Session()
a = session.head('http://www.google.co.uk')

session.cookies
```

> <[Cookie(version=0,
>   name='NID',
>   value='67=CXdvwjj9sjd-13Y0VyRQyUs8PxXaxyMhiGrrozXP7RWSjf-5alV4D17ORcfnZNYLAmlHXSVlHuS5LcuE4-v6vnzRQS-Gt72hgbGye0apoBoW5KJeVXA2o2E0gE-8jIeY',
>   port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.google.co.uk',
>   domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/',
>   path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1424443599, discard=False,
>   comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None},
>   rfc2109=False), Cookie(version=0, name='PREF',
>   value='ID=41c5d5cac7d22262:FF=0:TM=1408632399:LM=1408632399:S=wTfY_LkkZnSsBxoL',
>   port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.google.co.uk',
>   domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/',
>   path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1471704399, discard=False,
>   comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>

Now I want to change value of 'NID'

If I do `session.cookies['NID'] = 'abc'`, it would ended up with duplicated keys like the following:

> <[Cookie(version=0,
>   name='NID', value='abc', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='',
>   domain_specified=False, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/',
>   path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=None, discard=True,
>   comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None},
>   rfc2109=False), Cookie(version=0, name='NID',
>   value='67=CXdvwjj9sjd-13Y0VyRQyUs8PxXaxyMhiGrrozXP7RWSjf-5alV4D17ORcfnZNYLAmlHXSVlHuS5LcuE4-v6vnzRQS-Gt72hgbGye0apoBoW5KJeVXA2o2E0gE-8jIeY',
>   port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.google.co.uk',
>   domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/',
>   path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1424443599, discard=False,
>   comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': None},
>   rfc2109=False), Cookie(version=0, name='PREF',
>   value='ID=41c5d5cac7d22262:FF=0:TM=1408632399:LM=1408632399:S=wTfY_LkkZnSsBxoL',
>   port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.google.co.uk',
>   domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/',
>   path_specified=True, secure=False, expires=1471704399, discard=False,
>   comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={}, rfc2109=False)]>

My current approach is to do `session.cookies['NID'] = None` first, this removes the key/value, and then `session.cookies['NID'] = 'abc'` This sometimes works, but it completely ignores the cookies attributes.

What is a proper way of doing it?

Comment: Haven't tried myself, but have a look at `requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see, your cookie has no domain specified for it, so it's actually another cookie.

Using domain and path

```
    session.cookies.set('NID', 'abc', domain='.google.co.uk', path='/')
```

will set new cookie instead of the previously defined one.

`RequestCookieJar` is a wrapper for `cookielib.CookieJar`, but if you want to modify cookie attributes in-place (so that you reference the actual `cookielib.Cookie` objects) I found no better way than to use iterator.

If you look into the sources of `requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar` there are just no other methods that let you access items themselves and not their `name`/`value` fields.

Answer (score 1):

For me worked:

```
for cookie in response.cookies:
    if cookie.name == 'NID':
        cookie.value = 'abc'
        break
```